# Selectively suppress "unused variable" warnings for unused lambdas

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, compiler-warnings

Is there any way to suppress "unused variable" warnings for a specific file, namespace, or specific variable?

I ask because I have a namespace containing a big list of lambda functions. Some are not used now, but might be used in time. If these were regular free functions, I would not be warned if some were unused. However, because they are lambdas, I end up with a stack of compiler warnings.

I do ***not*** want to use a compiler flag to remove all of this type of warning, as normally, it is very useful to have the compiler catch unused variables. However, a stack of warnings about unused utility functions adds noise to otherwise useful information.

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: Depending of the compiler, there is some `#pragma`.

Comment: clang . . . . . . . .

Comment: I have not used clang, so I don't know. I have used Google, and this looks like it may work - http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2011/09/20/disabling-clang-compiler-warnings.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two approaches that come to mind. First of all, most build environments enable per-source compiler flags, so you should be able to turn off that warning just for the single file where all those lambdas are defined.

Then there is a general approach to silence such warnings for single variables: use it, but not really do anything with it. On some compilers this can be achieved with a simple cast to void:

```
auto x = /* ... */;
(void) x;
```

But more effective is defining a simple function that makes it look (for the compiler) as if the variable was used:

```
template <class T>
void ignore_unused(T&) {} 

//later...
auto x = /* ... */;
ignore_unused(x);
```

Note the parameter has no name, so the compiler will not complain about *that* one to be unused.

The idea is pretty common: do something with the variable that effectively makes no operation but silences the static analyzer that emits the "unused variable" warning.

Boost has a similar function, `boost::ignore_unused_variable_warning()`

For more information, see [Herb Sutter's blog](http://herbsutter.com/2009/10/18/mailbag-shutting-up-compiler-warnings/).

Answer (score 3):

In C++ you can `static_cast` anything to `void`.

What is the use of such a cast if it does not produce any side effects or a value one might ask?

Precisely to tell the compiler that an object is "used" in a portable way.

So,

```
auto x =  /*...*/;
static_cast<void>(x);
```

Comment: Which is ironic, since by doing so you're not using it at all.

Comment: [`static_cast<void>(x)` won't work on many compilers](http://herbsutter.com/2009/10/18/mailbag-shutting-up-compiler-warnings/#comment-1515)

Answer (score 2):

Lambdas are [just syntactic sugar for functors](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-lambda-closures.html).  Functors are a type of object (one that has `operator()` overloaded).  So the compiler will warn if that variable (object) goes unused.

I recommend the block-comment method for hushing the compiler ;).  Other than that, there's not much you can do to *selectively* and *cleanly* silence the compiler in the general case.

Note that if you have a more specific case, such as passing arguments in a function, you can [make the argument nameless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905228) if you do not use it.  Another thing you could do is [put a `(void)var` reference somewhere in your code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1486931/1830736) (although this is cheating; now you've referenced it!).  Lastly, if your compiler supports it (the almighty GCC does), you might try using [the `__attribute__((unused))` preprocessor directive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1487128/1830736) (use [`[[gnu::unused]]`](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#gnu-attributes) for Clang).

Depending on your situation, these suggestions may or may not help.

Comment: You say "Lambdas are just syntactic sugar for functors."   I used to think this, but I'm not so sure any more.  Consider:   `auto f = [](int x){return x+1;}; for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) f = [f](int x) { return f(f(x)); }`.  The translation to functor is not straightforward (I guess the capture-by-value of f would need to be implemented as a unique_ptr or equivalent, rather than just a plain member variable).

Comment: I'm confused by your first paragraph.  It sounds like you are saying "lambdas are pretty much like functors; therefore an unused lambda will get a warning just like unused functors do".   But unused functors do *not* get a warning.   See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5302848/g-does-not-show-a-unused-warning

Answer (score 0):

How about hiding the lambdas inside of generators.  That way they don't even get created unless they are used.  So instead of:

```
auto add_one= [](int x){ return x + 1 } ;
```

Use:

```
std::function<int(int)> gen_addone(void)
{
    static auto l_= [](int x){ return x + 1 ; } ;
    return l_ ;
}
```

Sorry, you'll have to wait till c++1y for automatic return type deduction.